# What tense is "You were unable to do it."?

Tags: tenses, sentence, past-tense

> "You were unable to do it."

Can you describe the tense of this sentence? Is it Past Progressive?

Comment: No, we can't, because the sentence is ungrammatical. Perhaps you meant 'You were able to do it' or 'You were enabled to do it.'

Comment: @BarrieEngland Sorry, A correct sentence is "You were unable to do it.".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The finite verb is *were* and it’s the past tense of *be*.

Comment: it is the imprefect ("were" as opposed to the perfect "had been").

Comment: @Mawg: It is not. English has no imperfect tense.

Answer (score 2):

The tense is **simple past** or **past simple**. Progressive tenses use /**-ing**/: *He is running* or *She was jumping* or *They had been eating* or *We will be groaning soon* or *You would have been driving for 24 hours by then*.

Comment: Progressive is not a tense; even in languages with progressive morphology, progressive is an **aspect**. English has only two tenses, present and past. The progressive is a construction consisting of a form of the auxiliary verb _be_ followed by the _-ing_ form of the main predicate. It doesn't refer to time but to continuity of action, and requires an active predicate.

Comment: Yes, progressive is an aspect. The verb-tense terminology used by most English teachers and textbooks is inconsistent and sloppy. I recognize only two tenses: present and past. (I just found a page that lists 19 English tenses!) Then there are aspects: progressive and perfect; voice: active and passive; mood: subjunctive; etc. And many more words that I no longer use. I should have said _progressive tense-forms_ perhaps.